# Calculating date difference in years using smallint and datetime data types in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a column that stores years as `smallint` in my ms sql server database. I have another column that stores dates in datetime format. What is the correct way to find the difference between the two in years?

I have tried this which worked but I'm not sure if it's the correct way

```
DATEPART(YEAR, show_held) - born
```

where column show_held is of datetime data type and 
column born is of `smallint`

Comment: Looks fine. Why yould it not be correct? Is the result as you want it?

Comment: For me its look good ,But you can try `YEAR(show_held) - born` as alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DATEPART` to get the part of date in SQL.

As you said you need year of date then `DATEPART( YEAR, [value])` is giving you `int` type value. Which is an integer type value and further use in any process where `int` type value is expected. Now this `year` is pure integer value and nothing to do with `date` anymore.

Coming to your question, another year value is present in your column as `int` type and you want to find the difference in between them which can easily be calculated by.

```
  DATEPART(YEAR, show_held) - born
```

So you final query is giving correct result as you expected, since they both are `int` type.

For more info on `Datepart` you may find this link. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What if I want to subtract a number representing years  from a value stored as datetime. For example  2009 - DATEPART(YEAR,died). This doesn't produce the correct result

Comment: it depends what is stored in your `died`. Can you give the value

Comment: Apologies. It was stored as smallint :)